# GVIM to find and replace with a carriage return

Tags: windows, gvim, vi

I'm trying to automatically globally search through a file in a Windows system and replace certain strings with the found string, plus a carriage return (^r^n, or something like that).  Here is what I'm using, but it doesn't work.

```
s/\d\+\./&^M/g
```

In other words, I want to open up a new line following every occurrence of the string. Any ideas?  Also, ^r^n may be overkill.  I just want a windows-style new-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `\r`

```
s/\d\+\./&\r/g
```

I'm unsure what you expect to be matched by `\d\+\.` - a series of digits followed by a literal period (AKA full stop) or decimal point.